# How to get sum of numbers using SQL query in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I am beginner in ASP.NET Web Development.Now I want to find sum of marks using SQL sum query. but It finds -1 as sum after query execution. Here is my code:

```
public double GetTotalScore(string regNo)
{
    SqlConnection connection=new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    string query = "select sum(Score) from SaveResult where RegNo='" + regNo + "' group by RegNo";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    connection.Open();
    double total = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
    return total;
}
```

How could i get sum using sql query?

Comment: Use ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteNonQuery.

Comment: How the table `SaveResult` looks like

Comment: Is there a single line of code that is asp.ne specific - or do you add random tags for technologies you just can not identify because you do not bother to do so? That is not asp.net, it is ado.net. It may be in a web application, it still is ado.net.

Comment: Just a note on the `-1` bit. If you look [at the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you'll see the return value to ExecuteNonQuery is "The number of rows affected."  In the remarks section it explains `For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command.` and then later `For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.` Since a SELECT isn't a UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE it is a "other type of statement"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string GetTotalScore(string regNo)
    {
        SqlConnection connection=new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        string query = "select sum(Score) from SaveResult where RegNo='"+regNo+"' group by RegNo";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);  
        connection.Open();
        object total = command.ExecuteScalar();
        connection.Close();
        return Convert.ToString(total);
    }    
}
```

It works,to getting sum using ExecuteScalar.

Answer (score 4):

ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected.

ExecuteScalar is the method you want.  It returns a single-value (a "scalar") to you.

```
public double GetTotalScore(string regNo)
    {
        SqlConnection connection=new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        string query = "select sum(Score) from SaveResult where RegNo='" + regNo + "' group by RegNo";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();
        double total =  (double)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        connection.Close();
        return total;
    }
```

You still have a problem.

```
   string query = "select sum(Score) from SaveResult where RegNo='" + regNo + "' group by RegNo";
```

You need to change to parameterized queries.

```
   string query = "select sum(Score) from SaveResult where RegNo='@MyParameter' group by RegNo";


        SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@MyParameter";
        param.Value         = "myvalue";


        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

/* now call the ExecuteScalar */

See

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06

Comment: Not an answer. Answers have to explain.

Comment: what no reference to parameterized queries?

Comment: beware of injection `RegNo='" + regNo + "'`

Comment: Rowdy bunch today.

Comment: does the OP expect whom ever answers to provide links as well as answers to every example.. I think that this answer provides an excellent starting point and if the OP needs more this is what `GOOGLE` and or other search engines are out there for.. `+1` btw